# Disable position request with google maps autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I've just add a google maps autocomplete (the one that suggest you, and store all infos like route, city, administrative fields etc) fields in my website.
My only concern is that every time my users reload the page and highlight this field, the browser ask the permission to handle user's location.
I really don't need it and i would like to disable it but i can't find this option in the documentation.

Someone could help me out?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The autocomplete service doesn't request your position, something outside of that is doing it.

In at least one of [Google's examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform), that request is made by the client code:

```
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```